# Understanding Application Context

Tags: java, android, android-context

I'm fairly new to Android / Java and need some guidance.

Can someone explain why getApplicationContext() cannot be resolved in the following:

```
private void readText(final String s) {
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                textToSpeech.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` is a member of the `Context` class. The given snippet would appear to not be in a descendant of `Context`.

Comment: That makes sense. This code lives a class that extends RecyclerView.Adapter. How do a specify a context for TextToSpeech to use?

Comment: Oftentimes a `Context` is passed via a constructor parameter. If you're already doing that, you can use that one. Otherwise, you could add such a parameter, and a corresponding field, if necessary. I'm not sure that having an `Adapter` handle text-to-speech stuff is the best design, though. It'd probably be better to callback to the `Activity`, and let it handle that. Just my opinion.